# Improve performance of my jQuery selector - remove the use of jquery.find

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
$item = $row.find('td[data-id="' + id + '"]');
```

$row is a jquery reference to a table row. Is there any way I can optimise this code? I don't really want to have to use the find function unless I have to. I was wondering if I could do something like:

```
$item = $($row + 'td[data-id="' + id + '"]');
```

but that doesn't seem to work. Is there any way in which I can improve this code? In my code this is called many times and seems to be causing issues in IE.

Comment: Can we see the HTML that this operates on?

Comment: I would have thought that using `.find` would perform better than combining the selector somehow. If you only use one selector, it will search the whole document, while by using `.find`, you restrict the search space to just the one row.

Comment: Why do you think `.find()` is a problem? What do you mean by "seems to be causing issues"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*without using find explicitly*

```
$item = $('td[data-id="' + id + '"]',$row);
```

though `.find()` is faster then then what i suggested

[image]

Comment: Doesn't that result in a `.find()` behind the scenes?

Comment: @nnnnnn yes it does which is part of the reason why find is faster

Answer (score 1):

This is a very small piece of code to try and optimise. You say it's called many times. You should look at making one call to extract all the cells you want, then operating on the resulting collection. Some HTML would help to see if that's really feasible.

Answer (score 0):

In your particular case you already have the first selection and wishes to search within that result

you can either do

```
//passing the $row as the context for the selection
$("'td[data-id="' + id + '"]'",row);
```

or

```
$row.find('td[data-id="' + id + '"]')
```

However the former will actually call the latter after passing a few `if`s so the latter will always outperform the former

using `.find()`is generally a good thing when it comes to performance. In compound selectors like

```
$("table td div")
```

The `div`'s are found and then filterended based on their parents and the parent of their parent after that. using find you can force the selction to evaluate from left to right instead

```
$("table").find("td").find("div")
```

The latter will executed faster assuming you have more `div´'s than`table`'s